# Control volume in android application delphi xe 7

Tags: android, delphi, audio, volume

I'm using FormKeyup procedure to on/off sound volume, like this:

```
if key = vkVolumeDown then begin
quadrum:= 0.2;
 if MediaPlayer1.Volume - quadrum > 0 then
  MediaPlayer1.Volume:= MediaPlayer1.Volume-quadrum;
 if MediaPlayer1.Volume - quadrum < 0 then
  MediaPlayer1.Volume:= MediaPlayer1.Volume.Minvalue;
 snd:= false;
end;
```

But it's working only to switch on/off the sound (plus-minus 0.2 doesnt work) and i just want to set

Comment: While I can't see why it's not working, I can see that the the statement checking if the volume is less than 0 seems a bit strange. I wouldn't expect the media player component to allow that in the first place - either it would raise an exception or automatically set to 0 (I'm assuming anyway). I can't imagine why it would let you set it to a negative, so why check for a negative? That check should be performed before the first check and make sure it doesn't become negative in the first place. Although I don't believe that would solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that instead of two nested if statments you should use if .. else statment. Why?
The second nested if statments is rechecking the MediaPlayer1.Volume - quadrum after you have already reduced the volume by the value of quadrum. So if the MediaPlayer1.Volume was 0.4 or less it would mute the audio instantly. Especially if setting snd to false stops the sound playback. Becouse this command would be always executed no matter what.

So instead your code should be like this:

```
if key = vkVolumeDown then begin
quadrum:= 0.2;
  if MediaPlayer1.Volume - quadrum > 0 then
    MediaPlayer1.Volume:= MediaPlayer1.Volume-quadrum
  else 
  begin
    MediaPlayer1.Volume:= MediaPlayer1.Volume.Minvalue;
    snd:= false;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Ahh yes, missing an `else` and a `begin..end`... Reminds me of my early Delphi days :-)

Comment: Well, it seems to be my silly inadvertence mistake, thank you for notice it. Anyway i understand, that this code is quet newbe, maybe there are some kinds of method to set application volume equal to current system instead of catching formkeydown ?

Comment: You could tie this to OnChange event of the TTrackBar controll where you would then use its Position value to calculate the specific volue level. This way you would get your users volume controll that they are probably used to as it is commonly used approach.

Comment: Or perhaps you might wanna use the sliding gesture of some controlls to do this. There are numerous choices. I recomend you take a look at some of the sample programs that shipp with Delphi to posibly get better ideas and to so hoow it is implemented. That is what they are there for.